# Remove last char from batch variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch variable called version with this value "2930.2323 "

Now i want to remove the last character (or all spaces). I've tried both ways but the whitespace is not removed.

```
// MYVAR is set at the beginning of my batch file by another source code
SET "MYVAR=%MYVAR: =%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't remove "Whitespaces", but SPACEs only (ie if it's a TAB it won't be removed unless you add another line to remove TABs too).

For your given string, I suggest another approach:

```
for %%a in (%myvar%) do set "myvar=%%a"
echo --%myvar%--
```

Note: that only works for whitespaces at the beginning or end of the string. A space in the middle of the string will split the string into two (or more). Also, some special characters will be problematic. But it will work with strings like your example ("Version numbers")